# How many steps do I have to follow in order to update a pass for passbook

Tags: web-services, push-notification, mamp, passbook

I made a pass already and I can share it to device by web service in MAMP or by app. Moreover, I also created a database 'passesdb'with 3 tables such as Devices, Registration and MemberPass. I also read passbook document of apple, but I don't really understand what I have to do next! When we register device for push notification, how we get device_id, and pushToken by using POST ? I am stuck now, anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To push an update you need to follow the steps below:

1. Build a RESTful web service to [this specification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011988)
2. Add an `webserviceURL` and `authenticationToken` to your [pass.json](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/Introduction.html)
3. User installs the pass on their deivce
4. Your web service, captures the `deviceLibraryIdentifier` and `pushToken`
5. You create the updated .pkpass bundle
6. Open a connection to the [Apple Push Notification Service (APNS)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html) using the Pass Type ID Certificate matching the `passTypeIdentifier` in your pass.json
7. Pack and send an APNS message containing the `pushToken` and an empty payload
8. Wait for the device to retrieve the push message and request the `serialNumber` of all updated passes matching the `passTypeIdentifier` (request may also contain a `passesUpdatedSince` tag)
9. Your web service responds to the request from the device with the `serialNumber` of the updated pass (or passes updated since the `passesUpdatedSince` tag).
10. Wait for the device to respond with a request to send the new .pkpass bundle
11. Your web service sends the updated .pkpass bundle to the device.
12. The device processes the new pass and if appropriate, displays a notification.

You've already asked several times how to achieve steps 1 through 4 elsewhere on Stack Overflow.

I think you still are struggling to understand the concept that it is not YOU that registers the device - it is the DEVICE that registers itself.

Until you have built a web service that can catch and store the `deviceLibraryIdentifier` and `pushToken`, you won't be able to progress any further.

Comment: yes ! I cannot catch and store deviceLibraryIdentifier and pushToken now.

Comment: how checks that the request is authorized?

Comment: I can't go into yet another extended discussion as to how to check this.  1. Create pass and store authenticationToken, passTypeIdentifier and serialNumber in your db; 2. Device registers a pass for passTypeIdentifier and serialNumber and sends deviceLibraryIdentifier, and pushToken with the authenticationToken in the header; 3. Check that authenticationToken from the header == authenticationToken in your database; 4. If yes - request is authorised, store deviceLibraryIdentifier, passToken and whatever other fields you need in your devices database; 5; Send back a 201 response to the device.

Comment: Thank you ! I will ask you for more detail when I move to another step !

Comment: Now I can save data to database. Next, how can I create updated .pkpass bundle ?

Comment: How do you currently create the .pkpass?

Comment: So when I edit any contents of pass table , I need to recreate pass.pkpass again in order to send to device ?

Comment: If your Pass changes then yes, you will need a new .pkpass bundle.  If nothing changes then return `204` for the serials request and `302` for 'Get Latest Version of a Pass' request.  [This library](https://github.com/tschoffelen/PHP-Passkit) can help you generate and sign .pkpass bundles with PHP.

Comment: You're welcome - perhaps you can help with my [iOS question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15808260/ios-utf-8-label-string). I'm sure you have the same problem with Khmer!

Comment: in number 6, do I make a push notification for a pass ?

Comment: Yes - you need to open a socket to the APNS server and send a push.  If you will be updating lots of passes frequently, you will need to build a server an keep a socket open to APNS.

Comment: how can I do it ? can tell some steps ?

Comment: [Here](https://www.google.com.hk/#hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=how+to+build+apns+server+php&oq=how+to+build+apns+server+php&gs_l=hp.12...1140.1140.0.1919.1.1.0.0.0.0.47.47.1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.8.hp.UfRQlDiyz1o&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.&bvm=bv.44770516,d.aGc&fp=8a613ff54b82a42b&biw=1552&bih=1214) is a good place to start ;-) - but make sure you finish your web service first because the update process will require all the methods to be working.