# iOS UTF-8 Label String

Tags: ios, objective-c, utf-8

I have a UTF-8 encoding string that I want to display in a label.

When I set a break-point and examine the variable holding the string, all looks good.  However, when I try to output to the log, or to the label, I get latin encoding.

[image: Xcode Screenshot]

I have tried almost every suggestion on SO and beyond, but I just cannot get the string to display properly.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *rawString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",m_value];

const char *utf8String = [rawString UTF8String];
NSLog (@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:utf8String]);
NSLog (@"%s", utf8String);
NSLog (@"%@", rawString);

self.resultText.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:utf8String];
```

m_value is an NSString, and in the debug window, it also displays the correct encoding.

```
m_value NSString *  0x006797b0 @"鄧樂愚..."
    NSObject    NSObject    
    isa Class   0x3bddd8f4
    [0] Class
```

I am using the iOS 6.1 SDK.

Comment: A const char containing the utf-8 string. In my actual project, this is combined with some additional text.  If I try to use m_value in the label or log, I also get the same latin result.

Comment: Do you get the same behavior when you do: `self.resultText.text = rawString;` ?

Comment: @alladinian yes, I see the Latin encoded string in the label (which is resultText)

Comment: can you tell how are you getting m_value ?

Comment: see updated question - it is being populated by a pre-compiled library, but it is an NSString holding a UTF-8 string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I finally managed to get to the bottom of this.

The `m_value` `NSString` was being set by a third party library to which I had no access to the source.  Even though the value of this variable was being decoded correctly in the (I.e. displaying the Chinese characters) in the debug panel, the string was actually encoded with `NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding`.

I was able to determine this by copying the output into [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/), and flipping encodings until I found the one that translated correctly into UTF-8.

Then to fix in Objective-C, I first translated the `NSString` to a `const char`:

```
const char *macString = [bxr.m_value cStringUsingEncoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];
```

Then converted back to an `NSString`:

```
NSString *utf8String = [[NSString alloc]initWithCString:macString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

+1 to @Vitaly_S and @iphonic whose answers eventually led me to this solution.  For anyone else that stumbles across this; it seems that as of Xcode 4.6.1, the debug window cannot be trusted to render strings correctly, but you can rely on the `NSLog` output.

Comment: Had to wait until the 48 hours were up before accepting - but have done so now.

Comment: Hey - this seems to crash for Cyrillic for example, any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, if `m_value` is a const char contained UTF-8 string you have to use this method:

`- (id)initWithUTF8String:(const char *)bytes`

```
NSString *correctString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: m_value];
```

It's incorrect to pass `const char*` to `@` formatter, because `@` means `NSObject`, so it will be always incorrect and can lead to app crash

Comment: Thanks, will check when I get back to machine in a hour or so

Comment: Sorry, my bad, `m_value` is being provided by a pre-compiled library, but having checked, it is already an NSString.  The above provides an error "Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'const char *' with an rvalue of type 'NSString *'

Comment: Ok, what do you see if you're just call `self.resultText.text = m_value;`? Do you see correct symbols? I'm asking, because you can't say that there is an UTF-8 string inside NSString. There is an unicode string, but you don't know about it's representation.

Comment: Had tried that very early on and got the garbled string.  Have since discovered that the string was encoded with `NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding`

Answer (score 4):

When I want to show khmer on label, I use font 'Hanuman.ttf'. This is code I use:

```
`UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hanuman" size:20.0f];

self.nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",itemName];
self.nameLabel.font = font;`
```

[image: set font]

[image: result]

I don't know this can help you or not , but this is what I did before !

Comment: Thks @smallgirl, this wasn't it, but I managed to fix it yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your variable **m_value** NSData, you can try the following

```
self.resultText.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:m_value encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```

There are many encoding available you can try them too

```
NSASCIIStringEncoding       /* 0..127 only */
NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding
NSJapaneseEUCStringEncoding
NSUTF8StringEncoding
NSISOLatin1StringEncoding
NSSymbolStringEncoding
NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding
NSShiftJISStringEncoding          /* kCFStringEncodingDOSJapanese */
NSISOLatin2StringEncoding
NSUnicodeStringEncoding
NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding    /* Cyrillic; same as AdobeStandardCyrillic */
NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding    /* WinLatin1 */
NSWindowsCP1253StringEncoding    /* Greek */
NSWindowsCP1254StringEncoding    /* Turkish */
NSWindowsCP1250StringEncoding   /* WinLatin2 */
NSISO2022JPStringEncoding        /* ISO 2022 Japanese encoding for e-mail */
NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding

NSUTF16StringEncoding      /* An alias for NSUnicodeStringEncoding */

NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding          /* NSUTF16StringEncoding encoding with explicit endianness specified */
NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding      /* NSUTF16StringEncoding encoding with explicit endianness specified */

NSUTF32StringEncoding                  
NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding          /* NSUTF32StringEncoding encoding with explicit endianness specified */
NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding        /* NSUTF32StringEncoding encoding with explicit endianness specified */
```

Comment: Why did you decide that m_value is an instance of NSData?

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work as I need the formatted string (in my actual code I am adding additional variables to rawString). I have tried converting rawString to NSData then back to NSString using your suggested approach, but no joy.  You can see on the left of the debug screenshot that the variables are holding the correct values in the correct encoding.